# index unrelated entities in same index with hibernate search

Tags: hibernate, lucene, domain-driven-design, hibernate-search

In our domain model we are using aggregates quite aggressively, ie we don't connect all classes through jpa-relations but rather use services that we can query for the related objects. So, lets say we have two example classes, Person and a Workplace that are related by reference rather than direct object-relation.

```
public class Person {
  int id;
  String name;
}

public class Workplace {
  int id;
  String name;
  List<int> personId;
}
```

Now we would like to build an Hibernate Search index that should index fields both from Person and Workplace. Is this possible though Hibernate Search or do we have to handroll our own Lucene-indexer and take care of all maintenance that Hibernate Search performs on the index ourself?

Are there other solutions that we should consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Hibernate Search you can easily make an index containing both, or you can have two indexes one for each entity but query them as it was a single index.

```
@Indexed @Entity
public class Person {
   int id;
   @Field
   String name;
}

@Indexed @Entity
public class Workplace {
   int id;
   @Field
   String name;
   List<int> personId;
}
```

You can then use this index to find matching Persons and/or Workplace instances.

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query q = ...[a standard Lucene query]
FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery( q, Person.class );
List<Person> list = fullTextQuery.list();
```

or targetting both types:

```
FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery( q, Person.class, Workspace.class );
List list = fullTextQuery.list();
```

or simply all indexed types:

```
FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery( q );
List list = fullTextQuery.list();
```

Comment: I tried this, it works. But the problems is the results weren't sort correctly. All Persion list, and then list all Workplaces.